# d3.format 1 decimal plus letter X

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I read [this entire article](http://koaning.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/html/d3format.html) along with the D3 docs for `d3.format`, but could not find solution.

For input 1.2942, I'd like the output 1.3x, so formatting is 1 decimal plus the letter x. What can I pass to `d3.format()` to make this work?

**Edit:** let me know if a working example would be helpful, or if this is sufficient. I know the body of the post is very short, but the question is simple and straight-forward as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is using `.1f` as the specifier:

```js
function myFormat(n){
    return d3.format(".1f")(n) + "x";
}

console.log(myFormat(1.2942))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```